# Matlab index exceeds array bounds

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have been trying to get the code below to work. The input is shown after the %. It gives the error that the index in position 1 exceeds the array bounds. How do I fix this? The input for A has to be a 2x2 matrix and b a 2x1.

```
function [x, success, errEst, xHist] = richardson(A, b, x0, tol, maxIt)
% input: richardson([2 -1;-1 2],[1;0],0,10^-6,50)
for i=1:100
r= @(x) b-A.*x;
alpha0 = i/100;
G = @(x) x+alpha0*r(x);
[x, success, errEst, xHist] = fpIteratorB(G, x0, tol, maxIt);

semilogy(1:length(alpha0),alpha0)
end
```

It gives the following error message:

index in position one exceeds array bounds(must not exceed 1).

error in fpIteratorB (line 14)
xHist(1:2, It) = H(xHist(1:2,It-1));

error in richardson (line 8)
[x, success, errEst, xHist] = fpIteratorB(G, x0, tol, maxIt)

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message. It should provide useful information about where the error occurs (I don't see an indexing operation at all in the code you post). Also show how you call this function (knowing what the input variables are is often necessary to understand bugs). See [mre].

Comment: I have put the error message in my question. I've put the function call after the % in the code.

Comment: Probably because your x0 should be a 2x1 matrix and you have just entered a single value in your input. The error is probably thrown from inside the fpIteratorB function - it is not an inbuilt function so you may need to post this if setting the x0 correctly does not solve issue.

Comment: This does remove the error! This time it gives the following error message: `richardson([2 -1;-1 2],[1;0],[0;0],10^-6,50)
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 2-by-1 and
the size of the right side is 2-by-2.

Error in fpIteratorB (line 14)
    xHist(1:2, It) = H(xHist(1:2, It - 1));

Error in richardson (line 8)
[x, success, errEst, xHist] = fpIteratorB(G, x0, tol, maxIt);`   Would you know how to fix this as well? I can post the fpIterator if needed.

Comment: Can you paste fpIterator? It just looks like yet another dimension error.